# how to use a form and controller to store inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a web app I'm stuck on deleting the elements that I have created.

I'm using jQuery to display thumbnail pictures and I'm trying to include a hovering `X` to the top right corner that will `on-click` delete the thumbnail and the original file upload before sending the form.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // This is where I create the thumbnail:
  $('#uploadImage').on('change', function() {
    resizeImages(this.files[0], function(dataUrl) {
      $('#photo1').val(dataUrl);
      document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = dataUrl;
    });
  });

  // This is where I am attempting to delete it:
  $('.hiddenImages .close').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.hiddenImages').find('img').data('id');
    alert('remove picture: ' + id);
    document.getElementById(".hiddenImages").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictureHolders">
  <div class="hiddenImages">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="uploadPreview" data-id="photo-1" style="width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenImages">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="uploadPreview2" data-id="photo-2" style="width: 100px; 
      height: 100px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenImages">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="uploadPreview3" data-id="photo-3" style="width: 
      100px; height: 100px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenImages">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="uploadPreview4" data-id="photo-4" style="width: 100px; 
       height: 100px;" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="inputs">
  <div> Photo 1:
    <input type="text" id="desc1" name="desc1" />
    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="photos" id="photo1" name="photo1" value="" />
  <br/>
  <div> Photo 2:
    <input type="text" id="desc2" name="desc2" />
    <input id="uploadImage2" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="photos" id="photo2" name="photo2" value="" />
  <br/>
  <div> Photo 3:
    <input type="text" id="desc3" name="desc3" />
    <input id="uploadImage3" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="photos" id="photo3" name="photo3" value="" />
  <br/>
  <div> Photo 4:
    <input type="text" id="desc4" name="desc4" />
    <input id="uploadImage4" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="photos" id="photo4" name="photo4" value="" />

  <br/>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to read the error you get ► `Cannot read property 'remove' of null`, meaning you are not having a reference to the desired element you want to remove. Why? ► `document.getElementById(".hiddenImages")` ---- `.hiddenImages` is not an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a handle to an identifier by using a class name inside `getElemlementById`

You should be able to simply remove the container of the clcked `x`, similar to this: `$(this).closest('.hiddenImages').remove();`

In addition your selector for the click event on the `x` might need to change as you are removing the container your binding to and as such any new `.hiddenImages` container will not have that click event bound.

You might need to update `$('.hiddenImages .close').on('click', function...` to `$('.pictureHolders').on('click', '.hiddenImages .close', function...`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // This is where I create the thumbnail:
  $('#uploadImage').on('change', function() {
    resizeImages(this.files[0], function(dataUrl) {
      $('#photo1').val(dataUrl);
      document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = dataUrl;
    });
  });

  // This is where I am attempting to delete it:
  $('.pictureHolders').on('click', '.hiddenImages .close', function() {
    $(this).closest('.hiddenImages').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictureHolders">
  <div class="hiddenImages">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="uploadPreview" data-id="photo-1" style="width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenImages">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="uploadPreview2" data-id="photo-2" style="width: 100px; 
      height: 100px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenImages">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="uploadPreview3" data-id="photo-3" style="width: 
      100px; height: 100px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenImages">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="uploadPreview4" data-id="photo-4" style="width: 100px; 
       height: 100px;" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="inputs">
  <div> Photo 1:
    <input type="text" id="desc1" name="desc1" />
    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="photos" id="photo1" name="photo1" value="" />
  <br/>
  <div> Photo 2:
    <input type="text" id="desc2" name="desc2" />
    <input id="uploadImage2" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="photos" id="photo2" name="photo2" value="" />
  <br/>
  <div> Photo 3:
    <input type="text" id="desc3" name="desc3" />
    <input id="uploadImage3" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="photos" id="photo3" name="photo3" value="" />
  <br/>
  <div> Photo 4:
    <input type="text" id="desc4" name="desc4" />
    <input id="uploadImage4" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="photos" id="photo4" name="photo4" value="" />

  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: This works excellently, and I feel like this is a question that will extend this, this is deleting the element the images are in, is there a way I can focus the image and delete that while keeping the element it's placed in? and secondly I need to clear the file that has been uploaded. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to remove the image element only you can use `$(this).next('img').remove();` instead. In regards to the file upload, do you mean the entries stored in `this.files[0]`?

Comment: correct the ones stored in this.files[0], also I'm noticing two things with $(this).next('img").remove(); one it's removing the first image uploaded and it also is deleting the entire element. I'm thinking it might be easier to create the image element with DOM manipulation and generate and delete them accordingly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hiddenImages .close').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.hiddenImages').find('img').data('id');
    alert('remove picture: ' + id);
    document.getElementById(".hiddenImages").remove();
  });
```

become:

```
$('.hiddenImages .close').on('click', function() {
  var img = $(this).closest('.hiddenImages').find('img');
  img.remove()
});
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately Nothing happened, I thank you for your attempt!